# Center a form in a div and display another div indented on the right

Tags: html, css

I am trying to center a form inside a div and have another div on the right that is slightly indented but I can not get the elements to line up.

How do I do this with CSS?

Also, is it possible to align the right hand div in the center on a new line if the content doesn't fit on a page?

```css
.lander-form {
  margin: auto;
}

.lander-add {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 50px;
}

.container-lander {
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

#OEPL_Widget_Form {
  min-width: 200px;
  max-width: 399px;
  margin: auto;
  font-weight: 300;
  background-color: #F9F9F9;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #888888;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  text-align: left;
  border: 3px solid #d9d9d9;
}

#OEPL_Widget_Form div {
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-align: left;
}

#OEPL_Widget_Form input,
button {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 3px 5px;
}

.OEPL_Widget_Form textarea {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 3px 5px;
  height: 5em;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-lander">
  <div class="lander-form">
    <div class="widget widget_oepl_lead_widget">
      <div align='center' class='LeadFormMsg' style='color:red'></div>
      <form id='OEPL_Widget_Form' class='OEPL_Widget_Form' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
        <div style='width: 45%; float:left'>
          <p class='small'><label>First Name <span style='color: red'>*</span> :</label><br><input type='text' /></p>
        </div>
        <div style='width: 45%; float:right'>
          <p class='small'><label>Last Name <span style='color: red'>*</span> :</label><br><input type='text' /></p>
        </div>
        <div>
        </div>
        <p class='small'><label>Your Message <span style="color: red">*</span> :</label><br><textarea cols="30" rows="5"></textarea></p>
        <p><input type='submit' name='submit' style='' value='Submit' id='WidgetFormSubmit' class=''></p>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="lander-add">
    <div class="laura" id="laura-935032319"><img width="200" src='http://www.freevectors.net/files/large/10CarsVectorSet.jpg' /></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need is `float:left;`. Your two divs that you want side-by-side are `.lander-form` and `.lander-add`. What you have is, `.lander-add` is set to `float:right;`. This is a common beginner mistake. Both halves of the page should be `float:left`, you would think it would make more sense to make one of them `float:right`, but this is not the case.

I made the width for `.lander-form` 65%, expanded on the margins, and made the width for `.lander-add` "auto". This should work the way you want it to, with the right half of the page appearing below the left, when the viewing area is small or resized. Notice the difference when you run my code snippet, between the result that appears below, and the full-size result page.

```css
.lander-form {
  margin: auto;
  float:left;
  width:65%;
  margin-bottom:20px;
  margin-right:15px;
}

.lander-add {
  float: left;
  min-width:20%;
  width:auto;
}

.container-lander {
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

#OEPL_Widget_Form {
  min-width: 200px;
  max-width: 399px;
  margin: auto;
  font-weight: 300;
  background-color: #F9F9F9;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #888888;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  text-align: left;
  border: 3px solid #d9d9d9;
}

#OEPL_Widget_Form div {
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-align: left;
}

#OEPL_Widget_Form input,
button {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 3px 5px;
}

.OEPL_Widget_Form textarea {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 3px 5px;
  height: 5em;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-lander">
  <div class="lander-form">
    <div class="widget widget_oepl_lead_widget">
      <div align='center' class='LeadFormMsg' style='color:red'></div>
      <form id='OEPL_Widget_Form' class='OEPL_Widget_Form' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
        <div style='width: 45%; float:left'>
          <p class='small'><label>First Name <span style='color: red'>*</span> :</label><br><input type='text' /></p>
        </div>
        <div style='width: 45%; float:right'>
          <p class='small'><label>Last Name <span style='color: red'>*</span> :</label><br><input type='text' /></p>
        </div>
        <div>
        </div>
        <p class='small'><label>Your Message <span style="color: red">*</span> :</label><br><textarea cols="30" rows="5"></textarea></p>
        <p><input type='submit' name='submit' style='' value='Submit' id='WidgetFormSubmit' class=''></p>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="lander-add">
    <div class="laura" id="laura-935032319"><img width="200" src='http://www.freevectors.net/files/large/10CarsVectorSet.jpg' /></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Pretty complicated when comparing this to using `flex`.

Comment: might be a bit more complicated, but a lot of people have to support <= ie9 still. It's still a helpful answer.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. Will play around with this too.

Answer (score 0):

Using `flex` is often a great way to deal with layouts. Try this on your `.container-lander` `div` to align the items next to each other as well as having them vertically centered (additionally, this will also wrap the items when there's not enough space to place them next to each other):

**CSS:**

```
.container-lander {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Here is a [live example](https://jsfiddle.net/fxt6eq4r/1/) (JSFiddle).

Comment: Thank you for this, will give it a try. Can the lander-add right margin set be a static distance even when it resizes and any way to stop this behaviour? If i wanted to centre the lander-form element is there a way to achieve this or would i be best to create an empty div on the left of this?

Comment: Why would you put a `margin-right` on the right element? Sorry if I misunderstood you

Comment: Wanted to also try and see if the form could always be right in the centre of the screen and the lander-ad hug the right hand side of the screen. Have drawn it as I don't think i explained it very well! https://i.imgur.com/R7bGu9A.png .

Comment: Yes, certainly. You can add `flex: 1` to the form to make it fill all the space that has not been taken up by the car section. Updated code snippet: https://jsfiddle.net/fxt6eq4r/2/